# Kivy: How to add buttons to StackLayout from a list

Tags: python, kivy

I want to use a list of values like  `['btn1', 'btn2','btn3']` to create buttons dynamically on my layout.
After that I want capture the name of the button when pressed
but I'm stuck at adding buttons step please help
This is my `main.py`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    btns = ['btn1', 'btn2','btn3']
    for i in btns:
        self.add_widget(Button(text = i))

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     MyApp().run()
```

and this is my `design.kv` file

```
<MyButton@Button>:
    font_size: 24
    size_hint: [.50, None]
    height: 60
<MyLayout>
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        size: root.width, root.height
        Label:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size: 120 , 120
            text: "Welcome"
            font_size: 42
            rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex('#5ee2e5')

        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True

            StackLayout:
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex('#5ee2e5')
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

                cols:1
                pos_hint: {'center_x':.5}
                size_hint_y: None
                spacing: 5
                padding: 10
                height: self.minimum_height
                top: self.height

                MyButton: 
                    text: "Btn1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by adding an `id` for the `StackLayout` in `kv`:

```
        StackLayout:
            id: stack
```

Then add a method in the `MyLayout` class to add the `Buttons`, along with a call to that method in the `MyApp` class:

```
class MyLayout(Widget):
    def add_butts(self, dt):
        btns = ['btn1', 'btn2', 'btn3']
        for i in btns:
            self.ids.stack.add_widget(Button(text=i, size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 60)))

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        ml = MyLayout()
        Clock.schedule_once(ml.add_butts)
        return ml
```

Comment: Great Thanks bro